# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm Trying To Create A Small Quiz About Guessing The Name.
The Error Comes Up When Im Removing Lowercase Characters From A String, And I Haven't Got A Clue About Fixing It Since I'm Still New To Python.
What Would I Need To Do In Order To Solve It?

```py
artists = open('artists.txt') ## IF YOU WANT TO EDIT THE SONG NAMES AND ARTISTS
songs = open('songs.txt') ## YOU NEED TO LEAVE THEM IN ORDER

songfilter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\/' #Lowercase Alphabet With Some Slashes To Remove "/n"

songsFiltered = [songs.replace(alphabet, '') for w in songs]

guessList = list(zip(artists, songs))

songSelect = random.choice(guessList)

print(songSelect)
```

Im hoping to receive an output, like

```py
('Billie Eilish', 'B G')
```

Answer (score 1):

song is not an string object (so theres no replace function) in your case it's a file(reader) object (TextIOWrapper).

To get a string you must read() the file,

like:

```
with open('songs.txt', 'r') as f:
   content = f.read()
   content.replace(alphabet, '')
```

Same goes for songs in your code, you can't iterate over songs, you have to read the file into a string array/list.